# ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed. Range defined by partition 1 in table is not a subset of range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to switch the partition from staging to warehouse table.

ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed. Range defined by partition 1 in table 'dbo.table1' is not a subset of range defined by partition 299 in table 'dbo.table2'

Please let me know the workaround to this error if anyone have gone through the same error in the past.

Comment: possible cross site duplicate: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/alter-table-switching-from-regular-table-to-partitioned-table-fails

Comment: Did u try increasing the range, if the 299 is the last partition of table2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Dissolve the last range

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION <functname> MERGE RANGE (<range_of_299>)
```

Re-create

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION <functname> SPLIT RANGE (<increased_range_of_299>)
```

Then try SWITCH.Let me know after you tried

Answer (score 0):

it helps me:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> 
ADD CONSTRAINT <CK_table> 
CHECK (date <= '20171231 00:00:00.000'/*MAX date for <CK_table>*/)
```